# How do I replace a string of punctuation using regex?

Tags: regex

I have a lot of comma-separated records that look like this:

> ”Alex Vestergaard”,”5”,”11”,”16395 days, 16 hours, 53 minutes, 31
>   seconds”,”2014-01-03 15:22:20”,”1403”,”María Fernanda
>   Luciano”,”27”,”38”,”3 hours, 17 minutes, 31 seconds”,”2014-01-09
>   04:08:24”,”1397”,”Aimee Suarez”,”1”,”1”,”33 minutes, 8 seconds”, etc.

I have to remove the comma before each name (after every 6th occurrence of [","] I want to replace [","] with [""]) Can I do this using regex?

Comment: Use an appropriate parser. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/303346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`((?:.*?”,”){5}.*?)(”,”)`

with

`$1””`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/f0pJal/1)

**Explanation:**

- `((?:.*?”,”){5}.*?)` - Group 1

  - `(?:.*?”,”){5}` - 0+ occurrences of any character(but not a newline) followed by `”,”`. Repeat this whole sequence 5 times
  - `.*?` - match 0+ occurrences of any character lazily but not a newline character so as to reach the 6th occurrence of `”,”`
- `(”,”)` - match and capture the sequence `”,”` in Group 2

Now, the whole match is nothing but a combination of Group1 and Group2(i.e `$1$2`). We just have to replace this match with `$1””`

Comment: Thanks very much! This is it :)

Comment: Is there a way to match for text only, so it matches the comma before the text? I notice that some records have fewer items than others.

Comment: In this case, it would be difficult because even if I write a sequence for a name, that sequence might match some other value which is not a name , thus giving you improper results. I wrote this regex, keeping your statement in mind: `(after every 6th occurrence of [","] I want to replace [","] with [""]) `

Comment: OK. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

May be possible to use regex but a simple loop will also do the trick...

assuming contents has your text:

```
values = contents.split(',')
size = len(values)
start = 0
result = ""
while start < size:
    result += ','.join(values[start, min(start+6, size)])
    size += 6

return result
```